# Wicket warning allow_url_include=On

Tags: wicket

From time to time I get the following warning in the logfile of my Wicket application:

```
04.10.2012 14:52:08,525 WARN  [org.apache.wicket.core.request.mapper.AbstractBookmarkableMapper] 
Unknown listener interface 'd allow_url_include=On '
```

What does that mean and how do I fix it? I tried Google, but I could only find results for the PHP configuration allow_url_include.

I'm using Wicket 6.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely an automated tool tries to exploit some PHP application. Wicket can't handle this request and prints the warning. Look in the access log what HTTP requests hit your server at this timestamp to see which request caused this warning.

It's safe to ignore this warning in this case.

Comment: You are correct! Someone tried a request for "/?-d allow_url_include=On -d auto_prepend_file=../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd -n/?-d allow_url_include=On -d auto_prepend_file=../../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd -n" ... is there a way to filter those requests in Apache so that it doesn't get passed to Wicket (because we are getting daily automated emails for every Wicket WARN log entry)?